# Is it a problem to book a hotel for X days but not be there for part of the booking?

Tags: japan, bookings, hotels

I booked a flight to tokyo and it was kind of a package deal, and so there were 7 days included at a hotel with our flight. So we have 7 days booked at this hotel, however since we wanted to go to Osaka on day 4 and 5, we booked two nights at Osaka at another hotel. I am just wondering if this is an issue and if I should tell the first hotel beforehand that even though we are booked for 7 days on day 4 and 5 we wont be staying there but will be back on day 7. Is it best to tell this to the hotel, or will it not matter since we paid already? Sorry if this is a dumb question, this is my first time travelling.

Comment: If you just go away I think the hotel staff will be quite alarmed when on day 5 housekeeping finds that _the room has not been touched_ since they made the bed on day 4. It will look like you absconded without paying -- they may rent out the room to someone else, and/or police may become involved. So definitely let the hotel know about your plans.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have done this before, actually more than once, and the hotel didn't mention it or worry about it. The room was paid for by someone else, and except for a few days I was staying in it for six weeks, I was planning to leave some things there, and basically I thought it would be simpler not to bring it up rather than try to explain. I can see it would be different at a very small hotel.

Comment: I've done it in Germany in a medium sized hotel where I stayed long enough to know the staff's names. Didn't tell them I wouldn't be there for a day or two and they never mentioned it. I was afraid of housekeeping noticing and worrying, but that never happened.

Comment: You should tell them, unless you have a very private reason for not telling them about you being away.
Think it from their perspective. The amount of people and logistics investment hotel owners/administration make for their customers is variable, but its a significant number.

Comment: Ill let them know, its not a problem at all, I really didnt think about it until this morning, and I wondered whether it would be an issue. Ill be on the safe side and just give them a heads up.

Comment: My trip is in a week, do I tell them in person or should I let them know now?

Comment: Are you planning on leaving anything in the room? If you completely empty it and let housekeeping enter, it's possible that they could check you out if you don't let them know

Comment: I have actually done exactly that a few years back in Tokyo, keeping a hotel room there while we were away in Kyoto for a night or two. Told the reception beforehand, but as is sadly often the case in Japan, you have no idea if they understand what you're telling them (apologies to our Japanese friends, but you must be aware that communication between foreigners and locals is often not a simple matter in Japan), so I'm not sure it would actually have made a difference. I think we had left most of your luggage in the room though.

Comment: Seems like an easy way to avoid the problem mentioned by @HenningMakholm would be to leave the "Do Not Disturb" sign on your door.

Comment: @HenningMakholm While I agree that telling them is a good idea, don't they normally have your card number on file (and/or have a prepayment) such that absconding without paying isn't really a possibility?

Comment: Telling them can't hurt, but you might just consider leaving the "Do Not Disturb" placard out for days 4 & 5.  You've already paid, so it's none of their business if you're sleeping there or not.  If it's a boutique hotel where they have to have someone there to let you in/out, then it would be polite to let them know.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Normally I just advise the staff and tell them not to make the room. It has happened before but never in Japan, but I don't expect it to be different. I even leave all the stuff I don't need for an overnight trip the times I've done the same.

Also, they don't really know you are sleeping somewhere else, you could have been partying all night, been stuck without transport back from a day trip, etc, so there are plenty of reasons people miss a night. You have already paid the room in full, so they have nothing to be worried about. Just make sure they know, particularly if you did not leave anything in there.

Comment: right. this is completely normal.  sure, just tell the staff "you're going away for the night" so they know what's going on.

Comment: From Canada for example, there are often have very cheap packages with charter flights and a hotel in a single location. You can book these for 7-14 days usually and it sometimes comes almost the same price as just the airfare. So a lot of people buy those and take some nights off to go see places they can't reach in a day trip. There are also overnight excursions where you can trek for 1-4 days but you still need the hotel before and after. I have done it and know many other people who did. Of course, it depends on the deal. In Ecuador, we do not see such offers.

Answer (score 25):

Assuming you intend and expect to pay for all 7 nights, there is no requirement you actually stay there.

Sure, you can tell the desk you may be away.  I would be stunned if they had an issue.

You could also set the "No Service/Privacy" indicator.  This is not an uncommon occurrence.

Comment: This.  I'm totally surprised by the number of comments expressing concern about the staff finding the room untouched... what you do with it while you've got it booked is entirely your concern.  If you go out to a bar one night and end up going home with someone, do you call the hotel to let them know?  Absurd.  If you're concerned, do exactly as Johns-305 said and put the Do Not Disturb sign up.  (Full disclosure:  I'm one of those who *always* puts the DND sign up as soon as I check in)

Comment: @AC: The first thing an absconder is going to do on their way out is put the DND sign up.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition How does one abscond with a hotel room?!?!? Either you paid and checked in, or you didn't.

Comment: @AC Many hotels, at least better run ones, will want to see you and the room at least every once and a while, [in the interest of safety and security](http://lodgingmagazine.com/do-not-disturb-honoring-guest-privacy/). If you keep the Do Not Disturb sign up for days, the exact number depends on hotel policy, and never let them in for anything at all, you'll usually get a call from the manager or a knock at the door. It's not a big deal, and usually only applies after a couple of days, but it's a good idea to let the front desk know you'll be away so they don't start worrying.

Comment: @ErikE Yeah, I was wondering that, too. Granted, many (most?) hotels charge you at checkout rather than up front, but all of the ones I've stayed at have your credit card number on file (and some even do pre-authorizations) precisely so that absconding without payment is not a possibility.

Comment: @ErikE: Many hotels charge at checkout, and it's quite easy to query a charge on your credit card statement. No matter how many question marks and exclamation marks you use :)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Absconding means stealing and is almost always followed by "with X", the stolen item. That's all I meant.

Comment: @ErikE: [That is simply not true](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/abscond)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Looks like the truth is somewhere in the middle. "leave hurriedly and secretly, typically to avoid detection of or arrest for an unlawful action such as theft." Leaving your room is hardly an unlawful action if you've paid in advance. If you haven't then that's why they ask for a credit card at check-in, and you will be charged. There's not much incentive to "abscond" from a hotel room.

Comment: @ErikE: Whether or not you think absconding from a hotel room is common, that _is_ what the term means.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition The issue I have is that absconding means leaving after committing a crime. In your scenario, the leaving itself IS the crime, right? Or are you saying that the crime which has already been committed is intentionally staying in a room that one has no ability to pay for? So that you stay a few days, flee, and only then the hotel learns the credit card was stolen so can't get payment? I can accept that, but that scenario is completely off topic for the question given, where the asker says payment had already been made.

Comment: @ErikE: I cannot quite determine what the purpose is of your continued interrogation. Do you have some useful point to make or are you just nitpicking ad infinitum? Because eventually one of us has to stop this farce and I'm afraid right now it's going to be me...

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I stand corrected and fully accept that leaving a hotel room secretly with the intent to avoid payment is called *absconding*. Thank you for educating me. No thank you for your willful nastiness.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition While I (really) do love a good SE semantic 'debate', I'm more curious as to what the DND sign would accomplish in that situation?  Guests are free to walk out the door (even if they're carrying a suitcase) so what good does the sign do?  Delay discovery?  Seems like once you've absconded your way out the front door it's a matter for the police, and I'm not sure how much an extra couple of days buys you.
(Oh, and Zach - while I don't dispute what you're saying at all, my anecdotal personal record is 2 full weeks of DND without getting checked in on.  YMMV)

Answer (score 9):

While my answer doesn't wholly apply to the asker's particular case since the nights absent are not at the beginning of the stay, in the more general case for other folks who have a similar question, it is worth noting that if one won't be present to check in at the *start* of the booking, one **definitely** should contact the hotel so they don't assume it is a case of no-show and give the reserved room to someone else.

Now, you almost certainly can only expect to keep a room available for your arrival that the hotel has been paid for or where they can ensure payment. No hotel I know of will maintain a reservation past the check-in time without receiving money or holding a credit card number for security, and if you show up for the first time on day two and all the rooms are gone, tough luck. Even a credit card almost certainly can't keep the room available to the second night without some form of check-in.

If you've paid in advance, being a no-show is acceptable and as long as you have notified them you can probably expect to keep the room. Don't do it too early as this puts a burden on them to remember for an extended period. Call on the day of the expected check-in.

If your payment is not in advance and you expect to pay at the end of your stay, there are a few additional considerations. First, you'll almost certainly be expected to provide a credit card for security, often at booking time and certainly no later than check-in time. Second, if you don't check in on the expected day by the expected time, everything I said above about check-in comes into play and you should no longer expect a room to be reserved for you, plus you may additionally be charged one night's stay even if you never showed.

Finally, if you do plan to be away from the room for an extended period (more than a day or two, though you theoretically could be risking problems even then), do inform the hotel. Even with a Do Not Disturb sign placed on your door, they may check rooms periodically, and if a room is completely empty with no belongings they may reasonably assume you have left without notice and check you out, so that when you return you find you have no room. Even belongings may be collected and the room retaken if it goes on for too long.

None of this should be surprising. Hotels make money by getting paid for rooms. Anything that could jeopardize their ability to be paid for any room is something they will take action to prevent. Failure to check in, abandonment of a room where they may not be able to charge the full amount of the stay to a held credit card, fear of a room being damaged so that it requires repair or can't be occupied for a period, and so in.

My answer is not specific to Japan so I'd be interested in any comments or improvement that can be made to this answer, but I think it extremely likely that no matter where you are, not showing up at the expected time to check in could put your reserved room at risk.

Comment: Even if you haven't paid up front, if the room is reserved for you then the hotel has agreed to hold the room for you, and you have agreed to pay the hotel for it.  You owe them regardless of whether you actually use the room.  The bit about checking in **is** quite important, though, as you've likely agreed that if you don't check in then the hotel can give your room away.  Sometimes the agreement states that you don't owe them in that case, but more frequently in my (mostly US/Euro) experience you're still obligated to pay for the room since they might not find a last minute replacement.

Comment: What you've said seems consistent with what I wrote, with the addition that you may or may not be expected to pay for a no-show reservation if you haven't already. Does that seem accurate? I'm having trouble figuring out what the main thrust of your comment is.

Comment: @ErikE: The disagreement between your answer and A C's comment -- if I'm understanding you both correctly -- is in the case of { absence at beginning of stay, didn't prepay, did check in }. Your answer seems to be saying that you "almost certainly" can't expect the hotel to hold the room vacant for you, since you haven't paid for it, whereas A C is saying that the hotel has committed to hold it for you, as long as you do check in.

Comment: The main thrust was primarily my (mis?)interpretation of your second paragraph -- I read it as implying that if the hotel finds your room to be vacant on day 2 after you've checked in but still have not yet paid, they are likely to rent it to someone else.  Re-reading it now, you may have still been talking about failure to check in.

Comment: @AC Yes, I only address the failure to check in scenario. Is my edit sufficient to clarify the answer?

Comment: I think the "once you've paid" part confuses things a bit. At least with nearly all of the hotels I've stayed in recently (across N. Amer, Europe, and Asia,) the policy was something to the effect of prepaid, non-refundable bookings are forfeited completely if you don't check in (or notify the hotel of your inability to check in) by x time. For cancellable rates, the policy is usually something to the effect of "if you don't check in by x time, we'll charge you 1 night and release your room." Some places charge more than one night or even the entire reserved stay.